# R: what is the vector of quantiles in density function dvmnorm

Tags: r, statistics, probability-density

```
library(mvtnorm)
dmvnorm(x, mean = rep(0, p), sigma = diag(p), log = FALSE)
```

The `dmvnorm` provides the density function for a multivariate normal distribution. What exactly does the first parameter, `x` represent? The documentation says "vector or matrix of quantiles. If x is a matrix, each row is taken to be a quantile."

```
> dmvnorm(x=c(0,0), mean=c(1,1))
[1] 0.0585
```

Here is the sample code on the help page. In that case are you generating the probability of having quantile 0 at a normal distribution with mean 1 and sd 1 (assuming that's the default). Since this is a multivariate normal density function, and a vector of quantiles `(0, 0)` was passed in, why isn't the output a vector of probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking bivariate normal `(X1, X2)` as an example, by passing in `x = (0, 0)`, you get `P(X1 = 0, X2 = 0)` which is a single value. Why do you expect to get a vector?

If you want a vector, you need to pass in a matrix. For example, `x = cbind(c(0,1), c(0,1))` gives

```
P(X1 = 0, X2 = 0)
P(X1 = 1, X2 = 1)
```

In this situation, each row of the matrix is processed in parallel.